# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040904

Tags: c#, xaml, exception, uno-platform

While working with UNO Plataform, at XAML mainpage, got the error "**Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040904**".

No restart VS, rebuild solution or other things worked.

**Solution**:

Was because of **Release** being selected, just changed the solution configuration to **Debug**, closed the xaml, and reopen (or reaload) and got it all working again, hope to help somebody else with the same error.

(on my way to 15 points so i could vote)

Comment: _"on my way to 15 points so i could vote"_ That looks to me as if you want to add more details to your Question, and then add an Answer describing the Solution you found

Comment: Applies to UWP as well.